# How to remove Google Chrome's Google search engine parameters?

Tags: google-chrome, search

A lot of parameters append to the searches we do on the address bar, here's a full list:
https://moz.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-google-search-parameters

I bookmark my Google searches a lot, and by a lot I mean I have more than 4 thousand of them. So I want the URL's to look tidy to identify duplicates better. The bookmarks are vocabulary look ups, like "Define *word*" etc.

Here's the search engines `chrome://settings/searchEngines`:

[image]

But I can't edit the query URL on the Google search engine:

[image]

And I can't make a new Google.com search engine probably because it would be a duplicate of the default Google search engine (the default google search engine can't be removed):

[image]

---

Seems like the question is vague? here's a better example:

When I search on the address bar which uses the default search engine which is google, I want my URL to look like this:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=Define+Word
```

Instead of this:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=Define+Word&oq=Define+Word&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j69i61l2.617j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Updated the question to make it more understandable

Comment: Instead of the actual search term, use %s in place of the search terms, when defining a "new" search engine.  I believe your method should only work when attempting external queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unable to change the active and default search plugin.
Steps should be:

1. Change default from Google to another search engine (e.g. Bing).
2. Edit Google.
3. Change back the default to Google from Bing.

Alternatively:

1. Create a new search engine - and name it something else e.g. Goog
2. Change the default from Google to Goog.

Comment: Thanks! so I deleted the default and created a new one and in the query URL I added `https://www.google.com/search?q=%s` works nice :D

Comment: woops! shouldn't have deleted it! now the search prediction doesn't work! xD fixed it by restoring settings, and instead of deleting went exactly with your alternative option :D