# Chrome right click option "search google for xxx" become mobile style, how to fix it?

Tags: google-chrome, google-search, search-engines

[image]

Open any website in chrome, select some words then right click them, then click "search google for 'xxx'"

Comment: Please go to https://stackoverflow.com/a/838755/11016652 and click on "Run code snippet". Tell us what the output is. If your DPI is set too high this could be the reason.

Comment: I think the question of the OP is about why the Google page is shown in mobile style. It has nothing to do with the side panel. He is right that for example the log-in button is missing and also the settings gear which are normally shown on the desktop site.

Comment: `Open any website in chrome, select some words then right click them, then click "search google for 'xxx'"` ... and then? Could you please clarify what exactly happens, and what exactly you expect to happen?

Comment: No repro. Please add more details, name and version of the operative system, Chrome version, screen size, what you have tried.

Comment: @zomega please take a look to my [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1769436/152004)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google added **Side search** -feature with Chrome v.106. To enable / disable the feature:

1. Open Chrome, type **chrome://flags/** in address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the advanced configuration page
2. Type `side search` in the **Search flags** box
3. To enable/disable the Side Search Panel, select Enabled/Disabled from the drop-down box
4. Restart the browser with the “Relaunch now” button

If you want to restore default setting in the future, select “Default” option from the drop-down box and restart the browser.

[Source](https://www.askvg.com/tip-enable-or-disable-side-search-panel-in-google-chrome/)

Comment: _Should_ it show if the Side Search is open? Apparently neither of us can tell. The OP really needs to update the question and clearly explain what exactly is wrong. Us guesstimating isn't productive.

Comment: While the flag might be helpful, IMHO it's not really needed, there are buttons to close the panel.

Comment: Please see my [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1769436/152004)

Comment: Oh, got it. There are indeed buttons and kbd shortcuts to close/open the side panel, but those don't prevent the side search from opening in the first place, correct?

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment to the question I was not able to reproduce the automatic opening of the side panel.

Comment: @Rubén - nice work on the URL parameter :-)

Comment: Typing `side search` into the search flags box no longer turns up any results as of Mar 21st, 2023. The direct URL `chrome://flags/#side-search` worked for me, or typing in `search web in side panel`.

Answer (score 2):

Tl;Dr: It's unclear what caused that `sidesearch=1` is added to the Google Search results query but apparently this is related to the **Side Panel**. Updating OS, Chrome and disabling extensions very likely to solve the problem. Alternative: use Chrome flags to disable **Side Search**. Proceed with caution.

---

No repro

Chrome version 110.0.5481.110
Google domain: google.com
Language: English US
MacOS Ventura 13.1

---

I opened the screenshot from the question in a new window in order to be able to examine it in detail. I observed that it includes in the URL the parameter `sidesearch=1`. Adding this parameter to the URL of a search results page (pre-pending `&`), the page results style change to the mobile version without showing the side panel.

Without `&sidesearch=1` in the URL

[image: Search results without sidesearch parameter]

With `&sidesearch=1` in the URL

[image: Search results with sidesearch parameter]

I *googled* for this parameter but I only was able to find a couple of files from Google Git for unit tests. From [one of this files](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/afd3c658f932029bb4953b1e2498a500799c6d7f/chrome/browser/ui/side_search/side_search_tab_contents_helper_unittest.cc):

> ```
> // Tests to see if `navigated_url` matches `stored_url`. We cannot directly
> // compare as the "sidesearch=1" query param may have been appended to the
> // `stored_url` to ensure Google serves the side search SRP to the chrome
> // client.
> ```

Anyway, I don't think that might be possible for me learn anything helpful for end-users, as this problem can't be reproduced under "normal" circunstances nine days after the question was posted, specially without having the complete details.

Other symptoms that might or might not be relevant

1. A lot of taps open
2. The Google domain is google.com.hk.
3. It's evident that there are multiple extensions installed
4. The page results show mixed language, some texts are in Chinese and other in English.

---

This problem looks to be part of **Side Panel**. It is opened when clicking the **Side Panel** button in the top right of the Chrome window and might be openend by doing other actions, i.e., when the **Side Panel** is closed, the Chrome address bar will show a button with the **Google logo** (G):

- Clicking this (G) button will open the **Side Panel**. As mentioned above, you might click the **Side Panel** button to hide the panel, or by clicking the **Close** button (X)
- Like in the case reported by the OP, by selecting "Search Google for...". I was not able to reproduce under normal circuntances the behavior reported, even when using a reduced window and Chrome set with a high Zoom in value (> 100%)

In the [previous answer](https://superuser.com/a/1767735/152004) it was suggested to use a Chrome flag. It might make sense as a workaround, but I don't think that it is necessary to use the flag as a permanent measure. By the other hand Chrome flags are intended to be used by Chrome developers for testing and for advanced users for troubleshooting. It's discouraged their use by corporate IT departments in production.

---

Just in case that someone is unfamiliar with the **Side Panel**:

- To hide panel, click the **Side Panel** button.
- Also you might close the **Side Panel** by clicking the **Close** button (X).

Besides the URL / query string parameter there might be other things that might cause that Google shows the mobile view instea of the desktop view like the use of a Chrome extension that changes the user agent.

Resources

- [Manage Chrome Side panel](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/13156494?hl=en)
- [What are Chrome flags?](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/chrome-flags/)

Related

- [Prevent tab change on contextual "Search Google for '{selected text}'"](https://superuser.com/q/912451/152004)
- [How can I view the mobile version of a webpage in Google Chrome for Desktop?](https://superuser.com/q/1214829/152004)
- [How to remove Google Chrome's Google search engine parameters?](https://superuser.com/q/1408742/152004)
- [Desktop Chrome stuck displaying mobile site](https://superuser.com/q/1621281/152004)
- [Is there a keyboard shortcut to show/hide the side panel?](https://superuser.com/q/1730031/152004)

Comment: Yap. TBH I don't _know_ much abt Chrome, I tested and dumped it way back yonder except for desktop-ing web-based apps/services like Salesfarce dot com. I.e. my answer here is based solely on troubleshooting skills (or lack thereof) & web searches. Close button would be my weapon of choice here as well; unless the side search popped up consistently - tho' I might actually find it useful :-)